# Trying To Perform .has() with .attr() to style more

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use an `if` `else if` statements for my jQuery to add multiple statements so that it is neatly done. Only problem is one I am getting a console error and two it of course is not working ugh!

Code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var NLG = $('.post .name strong a').has('span'); 
if {
   NLG.attr('style','color:#09B300').css({'font-weight':'bold'});
   }
 else if {
     NLG.attr('style','color:#09B400').css({'text-decoration':'underline'});
         }
});
```

I don't know if I wrote the `.attr` correctly or even the `.has()`

I am going to have alot more else if statements and well hope you understand what I want done here. Basically search for if the span as a style with the color base and if so had some more CSS to it.

Thanks to demwunz I have got the problem fixed, and understanding the if conditions a wee bit more thanks everyone!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var NLG = $('.post .name a span');
    var color = NLG.attr('style');
 if(color === 'color:#09B300'){
    NLG.addClass('bringingback');
    } 
  else if (color === 'color:#09B400'){
    NLG.addClass('takenback');
        }
});
```

Comment: You didn't write the `if`'s conditions

Comment: Where are the conditional statements for the `if` keyword?

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for stating the obvious, yes I am a newb LOL. Though anyways  I did learn something today, if statements need conditions HAHA. I am very grateful and would also like to ask does anyone have any good links to documentation of if statements so I could learn more?

Comment: @EasyBB, That's some nasty way to do it, but I'm glad it works for you

Comment: yeah it i can't add class names since this is parsed through php from a hosting site that me and members use. They set their groups name and color, and by doing this it places an inline. Sorry but this is the only way that it is possible. If i had control I wouldn't be using jQuery for this since it runs through the whole library when clearly I can go and add a class and skip this entire step. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented before, you need to pass an argument to the `if` statement. I like to store the values so they're easier to reference and less operations are needed to grab the them.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var NLG = $('.post .name strong a').has('span');
    var color = NLG.css('color');
  if(color === '#09B300'){
    NLG.css('font-weight','bold');
  } else if (color === '#09B400'){
    NLG.css('text-decoration','underline');
  }
});
```

Comment: ooo I like how you did that! So the if condition I can use a variable to set .css('color'); and use it in the if's condition like you did color === 'theHEX'   ? that seems simple enough. Yes like I've stated to everyone else lol I haven't used the if statements ever before.

Comment: you can put any truthy/falsy value into the `if` statement, so yes you could also use this to set additional values. If you have lots of values to set, you might want to just `addClass`/`removeClass` instead and do proper styling in your css.

Comment: Oops! I misunderstood your last question. You would use the if condition to **test** truthy/falsy value, the === is a strict match meaning it HAS to be that value. You would set the values using .css('color', 'theHEX').

Comment: yeah tried this code out and it's giving me issues, doesn't seem to want to take. Only time it does do anything at all is var color =NLG.attr('style','color');  but that takes the color out?

Comment: no thats not what I had what you wrote is what I need. really. Though it doesn't seem to want to take.

Comment: NEVERMIND got it to work haha. I'll post what I created from what you wrote.

Comment: This is being naive, colors won't always be returned in six-digit  hexadecimal notation. That's why I commented about using classnames

Comment: By doing `var color=NLG.attr('style','color'); ` you're saying variable colour IS NLG, set the attribute 'style' to be 'color'. So by setting a variable i.e `var` you just want to GET and retain the value. To SET the value you should just do NLG.css('color', '#0000') etc

Comment: ok so I guess this doesn't work since its adding the class to everyone element now?

Comment: please help me more. I'm just tired of this. the .css('color') does nothing but .attr does why is this? I want to search to see if that hex is there if it is give it that corresponding class

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write the `if`'s condition statements.

Based on:

> Basically search for if the span as a style with the color base and if so had some more CSS to it.

You may want to add some classes based on your color, this makes it easier to test against. For example, classnames `green` and `greenest`.

```
.green {
  color: #09B300;
}

.greenest {
  color: #09B400;
}
```

Then add them to your respective elements instead of setting them with inline styling. Now, you can use `.hasClass()` to test against a given classname.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var $NLG = $('.post .name strong a').has('span'); 
  if ($NLG.hasClass("green")) {
    $NLG.css('font-weight', 'bold');
  } else if ($NLG.hasClass("greenest")) {
    $NLG.css('text-decoration', 'underline');
  }
});
```

Comment: the inline is actually parsed through php and I do not have control over it it be alot easier if i could use a class selector to find it :) that is why I must use the `.attr()` i can see how you went about this. so I have to make a condition then open it up to tell it what to do. I haven't used the if statement that much. 
`if ($NLG.attr('style','color:#09B400')) {
$NLG.css('font-weight','bold'); ` ?
I didn't know i could write the css like that haha wow

Comment: @EasyBB, it is not a good idea to check against the color property. Colors won't be returned necessarily in six-digit hexadecimal notation, they could be returned in `rgb` functional notation

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any conditions for the `if` statements.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var NLG = $('.post .name strong a').has('span'); 

if(condition1==condition2) 
{
   NLG.attr('style','color:#09B300').css({'font-weight':'bold'});
}
else if(condition3==condition1) 
{
   NLG.attr('style','color:#09B400').css({'text-decoration':'underline'});
}

});
```

Comment: what are the condition1==condition2 ? sorry haven't used if statements much and just want to learn

Comment: Well, those would just be variables that you would set yourself to compare against. More recent answers have used conditions in the way that you want them to.

Comment: Yeah seeing it now, lol. Thank you @dylancross . Any good docs on if statements so I could read more about these?

Comment: Well, this is the best explanation of them that I know of right now, there are many different sections. http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptif.php